# Generate all possible string time formats for timespan C#

Tags: c#, string, time, format, timespan

I'm trying to generate the below `TimeSpan` string formats consisting of "h:m:s:f", with up to 2 digits for the hours, minutes and seconds, and 0 to 3 digits for the milliseconds.

Desired formats:

> hh:m:ss:fff
>
> h:mm:s
>
> hh:mm:ss
>
> h:m:s:ff

and so on.

I'm trying to do that using recursion but I'm struggling to do so I've tried doing the following:

```
//Key - minimum digits left
//Value starting digits count
private static Dictionary<char, KeyValuePair<int, int>> replacements =
    new Dictionary<char, KeyValuePair<int, int>>
    {
        ['f'] = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(0, 3),
        ['s'] = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1, 2),
        ['m'] = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1, 2),
        ['h'] = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1, 2)
    };
private static char[] chars = new[] { 'f', 's', 'm', 'h' };
private static string baseTemplate = @"hh\:mm\:ss\:fff";
static IEnumerable<string> GetFormats(string template, int startIndex = 0, int endIndex = 0, List<string> formats = null)
{
    if (formats == null)
    {
        formats = new List<string>{template};
    }
    string copyTemplate = template;
    char currentChar = chars[startIndex];
    int indexToRemove = copyTemplate.IndexOf(currentChar);
    for (int i = 0; i < replacements[currentChar].Value - replacements[currentChar].Key; i++)
    {
        copyTemplate = copyTemplate.Remove(indexToRemove, 1);
        formats.Add(copyTemplate.TrimEnd('\\', '.', ':'));
    }
    if (startIndex == chars.Length - 1 && endIndex == chars.Length - 1)
    {
        return formats;
    }
    if (startIndex == 0)
    {
        return GetFormats(baseTemplate, endIndex + 1, endIndex + 1, formats);
    }
    return GetFormats(copyTemplate, startIndex - 1, endIndex, formats);
}
```

But it doesn't seems to work, I also have a working version which is basically a brute force solution using for loops:

```
private static List<string> GetFormats(List<string> separators)
{
    List<string> formats = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < separators.Count; i++)
    {
        string format = string.Empty;
        for (int hours = 1; hours <= 2; hours++)
        {
            format += "h";
            string hoursCopy = format;
            format += @"\:";
            for (int minutes = 1; minutes <= 2; minutes++)
            {
                format += "m";
                string minutesCopy = format;
                format += @"\:";
                for (int seconds = 1; seconds <= 2; seconds++)
                {
                    format += "s";
                    string secondsCopy = format;
                    format += $@"\{separators[i]}";
                    for (int miliseconds = 0; miliseconds <= 3; miliseconds++)
                    {
                        formats.Add(format.TrimEnd('\\', '.', ':'));
                        format += "f";
                    }
                    format = secondsCopy;
                }
                format = minutesCopy;
            }
            format = hoursCopy;
        }
    }
    return formats;
}
```

Invocation:

```
GetFormats(new[] { ":" })
```

How can I fix my recursion method?

Comment: @mjwills I've included the constraints *consisting of "h:m:s:f", with up to 2 digits for the hours, minutes and seconds, and 0 to 3 digits for the milliseconds.*, I'm doing this so I can pass the array of formats to `TimeSpan.ParseExact`. My current version is not printing all of the combinations, most are missing.

Comment: `System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatinfo.GetAllDateTimePatterns()` might be a better starting poiint

Comment: @Plutonix That'd be pretty handy, I figured there must be an easier way of doing it, but I still want to do that for practice.

Comment: What use is a 1 character `h` or `m` ?  What time is `5:1:22`?

Comment: @Plutonix 1m or 1h will be 1 minute/hour

Comment: @mjwills This is correct

Comment: What is the point of this all, OP? If this were a serious business problem i'd just work it out in my head (trivial really) and maybe store them as string constants in an array.  That would be way faster, since you only have to do it once. Why automate? Why do you want to "generate" these programmatically? Thinking you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not trying to be a wise aleck, OP, but if this were a real world problem that needed to be solved by my team, we'd do it this way:

```
static public List<string> GetFormats()
{
    return new List<string>
    {
        @"h\:mm\:ss\.fff",
        @"h\:mm\:ss\.ff",
        @"h\:mm\:ss\.f",
        @"h\:mm\:ss",
        @"h\:mm",
        @"hh\:mm\:ss\.fff",
        @"hh\:mm\:ss\.ff",
        @"hh\:mm\:ss\.f",
        @"hh\:mm\:ss",
        @"hh\:mm"
    };
}
```

This is a one-time problem that can be trivially solved on paper. Assuming there isn't some unstated requirement (e.g. compatibility with internationalization) there is zero need to automate this.

If you insist on generating it (and insist that minutes or seconds can be represented with a single digit, which I have certainly never seen), you can do it with a bit of LINQ like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

static public class ExtensionMethods
{
    static public IEnumerable<string> AddPossibilities(this IEnumerable<string> input, string symbol, string prefix, int minLength, int maxLength)
    {
        return input
            .SelectMany
                (
                    stringSoFar =>
                        Enumerable.Range
                            (
                                minLength, 
                                maxLength-minLength+1
                            )
                        .Select
                            (
                                length => stringSoFar  +
                                    (
                                        length == 0 ? "" : prefix
                                        + Enumerable.Range(0, length)
                                            .Select(i => symbol)
                                            .Aggregate((c, n) => c + n) 
                                    )
                            )
                );
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var results = new List<string> { "" }; //Empty to start
        var list = results
            .AddPossibilities("h", @""   , 1, 2)
            .AddPossibilities("m", @"\:" , 1, 2)
            .AddPossibilities("s", @"\:" , 1, 2)
            .AddPossibilities("f", @"\." , 0, 3);

        var timeSpan = new TimeSpan(0,1,2,3,4);
        foreach (var s in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(timeSpan.ToString(s));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1:2:3
1:2:3.0
1:2:3.00
1:2:3.004
1:2:03
1:2:03.0
1:2:03.00
1:2:03.004
1:02:3
1:02:3.0
1:02:3.00
1:02:3.004
1:02:03
1:02:03.0
1:02:03.00
1:02:03.004
01:2:3
01:2:3.0
01:2:3.00
01:2:3.004
01:2:03
01:2:03.0
01:2:03.00
01:2:03.004
01:02:3
01:02:3.0
01:02:3.00
01:02:3.004
01:02:03
01:02:03.0
01:02:03.00
01:02:03.004
```

[Click here for working code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HI2Lc5) on DotNetFiddle.

Comment: They will be written by hand in the application, as I stated in the comments, I just thought it's a fun problem to solve and that's why I'm looking for a solution.

Comment: I was looking for a recursive approach but I guess this will do :)